# Can't set breakpoints on closing brackets in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

This is occurring in Visual Studio 2005, in an ASP.NET Web Application.

For example, if I try to set a breakpoint in the following code:

```
if (frustrated)
{
    bool cry = true;
} <-- breakpoint here
```

It will set the breakpoint on the indicator margin, but when I actually hit F5 to debug the application, the breakpoint will flicker on and off (the little red circle literally vanishes then reappears) before disappearing altogether. Other breakpoints will work, just not ones ending on a closing bracket. This used to work, until I installed then uninstalled ReSharper (either it broke it, or its just coincidence).

EDIT: Just to reiterate - this is something that used to work, but doesn't anymore. I know I can put the breakpoint on a different line, but this is not what I want to do. I want it to work normally again.

EDIT 2: Resetting all of my settings did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any security updates lately to .NET or VS?

Comment: Just installing/uninstalling ReSharper. Nothing to .NET/VS.

Answer (score 1):

Set the breakpoint on the line above it, instead of a closing brace.

If the breakpoint turns from a solid circle to an empty circle it indicates that the breakpoint could not be set usually because of a mismatch between the code and the actual binary module being loaded.  This can be fixed by building or rebuilding suspect modules.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently wasn't clear enough in my original post: this is something I used to be able to do, but can no longer do. I don't want to work around it - I want to restore original functionality.

Answer (score 0):

All projects opened while ReSharper was installed were affected. I went through each project and deleted the .suo file. After that, life was good - I can set breakpoints again!